# PayPal IPN returning empty POST

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm integrating PayPal Buy Now button in a website, currently in a Sandbox using [this method](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/standard-integration). I have implemented official IPN processing mechanism from [PayPal sample source on GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php).

It is redirecting to my specified page but POST data is empty. I'm using file_get_contents("php://input") for it.

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
```

I changed it to `$_POST` as well but both were empty.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried the [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator)? And I use `$_POST` in my IPN script. Works just fine

Comment: How do I work with IPN Simulator? It just sends a sample request to my processing URL, yes? Does it show a response it gets from it?

Comment: Yes. The IPN simulator sends a POST to your IPN listener and shows you what it got back

Comment: It isn't showing me what it is getting back. Just if the request was successful or not.

Comment: And, yeah. The same code works with IPN Simulator but not with sandbox integrated Buy Now button.

Answer (score 0):

The information you have provided is too little to help you.

However, you can try using a ready to use class like https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

Here is a tutorial to integrate it http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html

Comment: Can you tell me what else do you need to know in order to diagnose the problem? I will update the question appropriately.